# How to change page value in ext js store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How to change page value dynamically in ext js store... I am able to change extraParams using store.getProxy().extraParams but how to change page value

Comment: you would likely be better using a paging toolbar

Comment: what version of extjs are you using